# axis2 1.6.2.war Tomcat Server 7.0 deploy windows 2008 R2 internal server error

Tags: windows, tomcat7, apache-axis, tomcat6

i deployed axis2 1.6.2 war file in apache tomcat 7.0 or 6.0 (windows 2008 r2 server) and i am getting axis2 welcome page, but when i click on any of the below links

- Services
- Validate
- Administration

i am getting the internal server error in browser.

The below exceptions are from tomcat log folder- localhost.2013-03-11.log file

any one knows about this issue

help me to solve this.

```
Mar 11, 2013 8:44:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError 
at      org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.initConfigContext(AxisServlet.java:584)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.init(AxisServlet.java:454)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1088)
at   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5033)
    at   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5317)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:977)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1655)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

    Caused by: org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: User-specified log class 'org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger' cannot be found or is not useable.
at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.discoverLogImplementation(LogFactoryImpl.java:798)
at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.newInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:601)
at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:333)
at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:307)
at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:645)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.<clinit>(DeploymentEngine.java:76)
... 19 more
Mar 11, 2013 8:44:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet /axis2 threw load() exception
org.apache.commons.logging.LogConfigurationException: User-specified log class 'org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger' cannot be found or is not useable.
at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.discoverLogImplementation(LogFactoryImpl.java:798)
at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.newInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:601)
at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:333)
at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:307)
at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:645)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.<clinit>(DeploymentEngine.java:76)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.initConfigContext(AxisServlet.java:584)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.init(AxisServlet.java:454)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1088)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5033)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5317)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:977)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1655)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
          Mar 11, 2013 8:45:31 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
   SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class     org.apache.axis2.deployment.WarBasedAxisConfigurator
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.initConfigContext(AxisServlet.java:584)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.init(AxisServlet.java:454)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:865)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:136)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
  Mar 11, 2013 8:45:31 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
  SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet AxisServlet
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class   org.apache.axis2.deployment.WarBasedAxisConfigurator
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.initConfigContext(AxisServlet.java:584)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.init(AxisServlet.java:454)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:865)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:136)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not about Log4j its about commons-logging. Your application try to redirect commons-logging logs to Log4j. It will be defined in properties files for commons logging. In order to make this work you must provide commons-logging library too.

Comment: i think the main exception is this                                                                      java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError 
at      org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.initConfigContext(AxisServlet.java:584)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.init(AxisServlet.java:454)

Comment: when i tested this application in development environment, it works fine. but when i deployed it in client place got this exception.

Comment: Did you check that commons-logging library is on the classpath of your application? It throws ExceptionInInitializerError because loggers usually configurated at startup. Check your servlet-container's lib on development and on client.

Comment: thanks bhdrkn: your are correct one of the classpath leads to commons logging jar which is 1.1 version . once i removed the path i got the axis2 services correctly. thank once again

Answer (score 1):

Seems like log4j logging library is not added in the build path. Make sure that Log4j jar is in your build path before u proceed.

Comment: log4j jar is present in axis2 lib folder. is there something else i am doing wrong

Comment: Is that added to the build path?

Comment: i am directly deploying the axis2.war file in apache tomcat webapp. and the library jar files will be in lib folder. and if i am correct web container will take care of library files

Answer (score 0):

You can get around the issue by using SimpleLog instead of Log4JLogger.

In webapps/axis2/WEB-INF/classes/commons-logging.properties comment out the line with Log4JLogger and uncomment the line with SimpleLog:

> org.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SimpleLog

(I'm running Tomcat 7.0.54 on Linux, but this workaround will probably work on other versions as well.)